# Custom init or public properties What is the best way to send parameters between viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, init

I would like to know which is the best way to send parameters between viewControllers. I know there are two possibilities, pass the parameters in the public properties after the init call.

```
ViewController *vc = [ViewController alloc] init];
vc.propertyOne = @"whatever";
vc.propertyTwo = @"whatever2";
```

Or creating a new Custom init like

```
initWithProperty:(NSString *)prperty1 andPropertyTwo:(NSString *)property2 
{
  self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.propertyOne = prperty1;
        self.propertyTwo = property2;
    }
    return self;

}

ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithProperty:@"whatever andPropertyTwo:@"xxxx"];
```

I would like to know Advantages and disadvantages of each one, and "when" and "why" is better use one of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass parameters to a custom `init` method if those values are needed immediately in the implementation of the `init` method.

You should use properties, that are set just after calling `alloc/init`, if you have several properties to set and those properties aren't needed in the `init` method itself.

Many times the properties aren't needed until `viewDidLoad` (in the case of a view controller) so using properties is cleaner. You don't want to end up with an `init` method with a dozen parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I had seen both ways but I could not understand why. Now, I get it.